# How can I import Array<Mat> to JNI from Kotlin?

Tags: c++, angular, android-studio, opencv, kotlin

I am new to coding JNI,
So my problem was when I debugging my Android Studio, it gives me this "error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'cv::Mat'"
And I don't know why. I guess it's because of how I try to change from 'jlong' and 'jlongArray' to 'Mat'. My native-lib.cpp was:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
Java_com_android_example_panoramacamera_fragments_CameraFragment_imagesPass(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                            jobject thiz, jlongArray image_in_,
                                                                            jlong image_out_) {
    // TODO: implement imagesPass()
    Stitcher::Mode mode = Stitcher::PANORAMA;
    Mat *image_in = (Mat*) image_in_, *image_out = (Mat*) image_out_;

    // Create a Stitcher class object with mode panoroma
    Ptr<Stitcher> stitcher = Stitcher::create(mode, false);

    // Command to stitch all the images present in the image array
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher->stitch(*image_in, *image_out);
    if(status == Stitcher::OK){
        return (jlong) image_out;
    }
}
```

And my kotlin-sript:

```
    private external fun imagesPass(imageIn: LongArray, imageOut: Long): Long

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == pickImageCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                if (data.clipData != null) {
                    val count = data.clipData!!.itemCount
                    for (i in 0 until count) {
                        val imageUri = data.clipData!!.getItemAt(i).uri
                        val imageStream: InputStream? = context?.contentResolver?.openInputStream(imageUri)
                        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)
                        val mat = Mat()
                        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat)
                        imagesMat[i] = mat
                    }
                }
                else {
                    val imageUri = data.data
                    val imageStream: InputStream? = imageUri?.let { context?.contentResolver?.openInputStream(it) }
                    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)
                    val mat = Mat()
                    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat)
                    imagesMat[0] = mat
                }
            }
            for(i in imagesMat.indices){
                longArray[i] = imagesMat[i].nativeObj
            }
            long = imagesPass(longArray, imageStitch.nativeObj)
            imageStitch =  Mat(long)
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```

and as you can see, I have tried to import Mat but since jni.h is so limited in its language, I have to convert my Mat to Long so I can use both Array and Mat.
But then my "opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp" start to show error:

```
inline Mat _InputArray::getMat(int i) const
{
    if( kind() == MAT && i < 0 )
        return *(const Mat*)obj; //This line gets error
    return getMat_(i);
}
```

So my question is how can I convert from jlongArray to InputArray? or How can I import Array to JNI from Kotlin?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Doing something like

```
Mat *image_in = (Mat*) image_in_
```

is incorrect code. For all practical purposes, always treat all JNI objects as **opaque** objects, making *no assumption* as to how they store the actual underlying data and instead use the JNI APIs to manipulate these objects, including retrieving the actual data from them. A `jlongArray` is **not equivalent** to something like `jlong array[] = {1, 2, 3}`.

From what I understand, you need access to the underlying native elements from the Java `jlongArray`. There are 2 possible options:

1. Get the backing native elements using `GetLongArrayElements()`. This provides a native array of `jlong`s which is valid until `ReleaseLongArrayElements()` is called.
2. Create a copy of a range of elements from the `jlongArray` using `GetLongArrayRegion()` that provides a copy of the buffer into a `jlong*` buffer. This buffer's life is *not* tied to the actual `jlongArray`. If the elements from this buffer need to be copied back to the original `jlongArray` then `SetLongArrayRegion()` can be used.

Once you have access to the native buffers, then they can be used in C++ code as usual like an array of `long`s.

An example for a solution with the 1st approach would look something like:

```
Java_com_android_example_panoramacamera_fragments_CameraFragment_imagesPass
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz, jlongArray imageIn, jlong ImageOut) {
      jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(imageIn);
      jlong * nativeImageList = env->GetLongArrayElements(imageIn, NULL);
      //Now one can do something like
      //Mat* image_in = reinterpret_cast<Mat*>(nativeImageList);
      //This should give the native version of images
      for(jsize idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
          std::printf("%zd ", nativeImageList[idx]);
      }
      std::printf("\n");
      //Once done with the array, release it back to JVM
      env->ReleaseLongArrayElements(imageIn, nativeImageList, 0);
      return ImageOut;
  }
```

In the above piece of code, the `nativeImageList` is an array of `jlong` which is *equivalent* to what was passed in from the Java/Kt layer into `longArray`. Each of the elements in this `nativeImageList` will be the same as what was stored with the line

```
longArray[i] = imagesMat[i].nativeObj
```

Hence `nativeImageList[0]` shall be the value of `imagesMat[0].nativeObj` and so on. This is obviously a handle to the underlying image and can be just used as

```
Mat* image_in = reinterpret_cast<Mat*>(nativeImageList);
```

Note the difference from

```
Mat* image_in = (Mat*) image_in_
```

Here, the *native* elements are retrieved and then cast into `Mat*`, not directly from the `jlongArray` object.

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html)

Comment: I still don't understand your answer. Can you explain to me again?

Comment: @HungDoan I've updated my answer to show some sample code. Check if that helps you understand and accomplish what you want to do.